# Is there a function $s(n)$ which tells the amount of factors any $n$ has?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, terminology, arithmetic-functions, divisor-counting-function

Is there a function $s(n)$ which tells the amount of factors any $n$ has? And if not, is it possible to write one?

Comment: Is [*this function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes there is. You just defined it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called the [**Divisor (Counting) Function**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), usually denoted $\tau(n)$, $\sigma_0(n)$ or (less fancy) $d(n)$.

If $n=\prod_{k=1}^rp_k^{a_k}$ is the prime factorisation of $n$, we have
$$\tau(n)=\prod_{k=1}^r(a_k+1).$$

For questions about it, see [divisor-counting-function](/questions/tagged/divisor-counting-function).

Comment: Thanks for this clear and direct answer. Could you please explicitly define $a_k$ and $r$ for me? I'm just a little confused on what those values represent.

Comment: $p_k$ are the prime numbers dividing $n$, $r$ is the number of distinct primes that divide $n$, $a_k$ is the largest integer for which $p_k^{a_k}$ divides $n$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Prime_Decomposition but I don't think I should write about prime factorization here, so I'm leaving the answer as is.